# Are there national accents that are "perfect neutral" for English?

Tags: english, native-language

I am French and I spent my days speaking English with people from various nations for the last 25 years.

I heard English spoken in many different ways, some were easy to understand, and some difficult. French pronunciation lays somewhere at the bottom, and I find Germans speaking English very understandable.

Vocabulary and grammar aside, **are there "national accents" (with all disclaimers this brings) that are recognized to be "perfectly neutral" for English?** In other words, are non-native speakers of English from a particular country recognized as being statistically the easiest to understand for other non-native speakers?

Comment: The question might be better suited for "English Language & Usage". I do like it being non-native English speaker myself. Just not sure it belongs to Linguistics.SE.

Comment: @tum_: I had that idea too, but ultimately chose Linguistics SE because EL&U SE is probably populated by mostly native English speakers. But sure, I am open to anything.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit of a grey area. The natives are not interested, and the linguists don't give a damn either :)

Comment: Are you talking just about phonetic factors or also about familiarity? Because (at least until recently, and I think still) English speakers round the world understand American accents (including some regional ones) better than Americans understand accents from elsewhere, but I think that is entirely due to asymmetrical exposure.

Comment: I think it depends massively on which non-native speakers you have in mind - what their L1 is and what model of English is (mainly) used in their education system. Very probably there will be a particular accent that is neutral for the greatest number of people, but it may be a long way from neutral for a large minority.